# how to create context menu for listview

Tags: android

I have created a dialogbox, inside that dialogbox I have a listview. I have created a context menu for that listView. It's showing context menu but when I'm clicking on that contextmenu item, it is not working.

Could anyone please help me about this.

Comment: are you handling the event onContextItemSelected correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the following code By using that You can Create Context Menu Inside the Listview::

1. Create Function

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       int menuItemId = item.getItemId();

       //to find out the id
       AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

       int currentSelectionItemPosition = menuInfo.position;

       //moving the cursor to the selected position in the list view
       restaurantFavoritesCursor.moveToPosition(currentSelectionItemPosition);
       int restaurantid = restaurantFavoritesCursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);

       if(menuItemId == R.id.deleteFavoriteRestaurant)
       {
           //write the Action
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Register the event in Oncreate or Inside the OnStart

registerForContextMenu(listviewobject);

try the above code I hope it will work.